# ls -lt not working in SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, ls, sort

I log into sftp:

```
sftp user@server
```

Then I run:

```
ls -lt
```

I expect files to be sorted by date.

```
sftp>  ls -lt *.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       5073032 Mar 14 08:42 file1.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       5073032 Mar 15 08:41 file2.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       5073032 Mar 16 08:41 file3.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       5072802 Mar 17 08:42 file4.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       1117736 Sep 30 14:44 file5.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       1120419 Oct  2 08:45 file6.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       1119763 Oct  1 08:43 file7.csv
-rw-------    0 76547986 200       5073258 Mar 13 08:41 file8.csv
```

But they are not.

Here is the version of OpenSSH

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Any idea why date sorting for ls in sftp is not working?

NOTE: ls -lt works in bash on the sftp server just not through sftp prompt. Maybe a bug in sftp?

Comment: Sorting seems to work on my systems when I don't have a glob (`ls -lt`) but when * add a glob (`ls -lt *.log`) it breaks.

Comment: It seems to work ok without the `*`.

Comment: I am not great with C, but the function for handling ls with a glob (`do_globbed_ls`) is completely different from the function for handling an ls without a glob (`do_ls_dir`).  The glob function doesn't seem to have a sort.  https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sftp.c#L1528

Comment: One easy work-around is to `sshfs` and use normal utilities (bash `ls -lt` and many more). Despite its name,  `sshfs` doesn't require full-blown `ssh` access; it is reality intended to abstract the deficient `sftp` away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `ls` argument includes a mask (and the mask does not match a single folder only), all sorting flags are ignored.

Note a lack of `LS_*_SORT` flags use in the [`do_globbed_ls` function](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6d5a41b38b55258213ecfaae9df7a758caa752a1/sftp.c#L882).

Contrary to non-globbed [`do_ls_dir`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6d5a41b38b55258213ecfaae9df7a758caa752a1/sftp.c#L796).

---

It seems like a bug to me. Hence I have posted a bug report:
[sftp ls command ignores sorting flags for globbed listing](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2694)

A fix is included since OpenSSH 7.6.